# All combinations of 2D array with mutual exclusivity

Tags: php, algorithm, combinations, permutation, mutual-exclusion

I have an array that looks like this:

```
$i[0] = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
$i[1] = ['d', 'e'];
$i[2] = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
$i[3] = ['d', 'e'];
$i[4] = ['f', 'g', 'h'];
```

I want to get all the possible permutations or combinations of this array, but without using the same value twice from two or more sub-arrays. So for instance, the result `a d b e f` would be possible, but not `a d a d f`.

I have tried basic permutation algorithms, but I can't wrap my head around how to modify it to do what I want.

Here's what I've got currently:

```
function array_permutation(array $a){
    $count = array_map('count', $a);
    $finalSize = 1;

    foreach ($count as $val) {
        $finalSize *= $val;
    }

    $output = [];

    for ($i = 0; $i < $finalSize; $i++) {
        $output[$i] = [];
        for ($c = 0; $c < count($a); $c++) {
            $index = ($i + $finalSize) % $count[$c];
            array_push($output[$i], $a[$c][$index]);
        }
    }
    return $output;
}
```

Comment: $i[0],$i[1] each one is again an array right ?

Comment: Yeah, sub-arrays of `$i`.

Comment: have you checked what are the total number of combinations even with duplicated?

Comment: It's 108 with the duplicated values.

Comment: The simplest way would be to calculate a cartesian product and remove entries with duplicates. Look up `array_cartesian`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very simple approach will be plain loop:

```
function decartProductExclusive($one, $two)
{
   $result = [];
   for($i=0; $i<count($one); $i++)
   {
      for($j=0; $j<count($two); $j++)
      {
         if(!count(array_intersect((array)$one[$i], (array)$two[$j])))
         {
            $result[]=array_merge((array)$one[$i], (array)$two[$j]);
         }
      }
   }
   return $result;
}

function createAssociation()
{
   $args   = func_get_args();
   if(!count($args))
   {
      return [];
   }
   $result = array_shift($args);
   while($array=array_shift($args))
   {
      $result=decartProductExclusive($result, $array);
   }
   return $result;
}

$i[0] = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
$i[1] = ['d', 'e'];
$i[2] = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
$i[3] = ['d', 'e'];
$i[4] = ['f', 'g', 'h'];

$result = call_user_func_array('createAssociation', $i);
```

(check the [fiddle](http://3v4l.org/PcnNf)) Your issue is about evaluating [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product), but with condition, that tuple can not contain repeated elements. This condition, however, may be fulfilled without evaluating intersection in each iteration (that will be an overkill). Instead you can filter resulting array, using [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/array_unique), like in [this](http://3v4l.org/vrmGm) fiddle.